# Why does refresh on excel not finish

Tags: sql-server, excel

So I have a view created on SQL server and I want to load it onto an excel sheet, but when the rows load onto the sheet they just keep loading and don't stop. For example it will have loaded 10 million rows when there isn't even that many and will still keep loading rows. What error is causing this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the query in sql server which is causing this error. There is statements within the query which are not needed and include fields that are not being used in the excel sheet. I've had this before and by doing this the correct rows would load onto the sheet. Another method if that doesn't work would just be to create the view again and add the tables and select columns needed.